# How to get result of DISP as return parameter into a variable?

Tags: matlab

Both functions `disp` and `display` do not have return parameters and 
display variable content into command window.

I would like to get the result of function call (displayed string) into a 
variable instead of output into command window, something like this `str = ToString( myStruct );` where input variable is a MATLAB struct!

I am aware that display result depends on available width of command window, it can be either wide or narrow.

In all modern programming languages it would be a `obj.ToString()` method.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`toString = @(x) evalc('disp(x)')`

Not pretty, but it should get the job done.

Answer (score 2):

[struct2str](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15017-struct2str) might be a solution for your problem.

Comment: +1 but I think there is also a general solution, not only for structs.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `sprintf`. You can write your own function for your data type if needed.

Comment: That's exactly what I did not want to do. This post reflects my approach http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/07/nobody-hates-software-more-than-software-developers.html