# How do I capture the output from the "present" function and store it in a string

Tags: matlab, text-capture

In Matlab, I have a IDPOLY object which I wish to "present" and store the resulting text in a text file.

eg if `a` is an IDPOLY object and I do

`>> present(a)`

I get

```
Discrete-time IDPOLY model: A(q)y(t) = B(q)u(t) + e(t)                
A(q) = 1 - 1.31 q^-1 + 0.2425 q^-2 - 0.431 q^-3 + 0.4987 q^-4         

B1(q) = 0.01357 + 0.04006 q^-1 - 0.04489 q^-2 + 0.007757 q^-3         
              - 0.1761 q^-4 + 0.06396 q^-5 - 0.2874 q^-6 + 0.3835 q^-7


B2(q) = -0.006397                                                     

Estimated using ARX with focus on data set iddata_est_shift           
Loss function 0.0617185 and FPE 0.061879                              
Sampling interval: 0.025                                              
Created:       24-Nov-2010 13:05:10                                   
Last modified: 24-Nov-2010 13:06:56
```

Does anyone know how to capture this text as I'd like to write it to a text file in a log file.  There are no returned arguments from `present`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get result of DISP as return parameter into a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862815/how-to-get-result-of-disp-as-return-parameter-into-a-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the evalc() command which does exactly what I need.

```
evalc

Evaluate MATLAB expression with capture
Syntax

T = evalc(S)
[T, X, Y, Z, ...] = evalc(S)
```

and pass the expression as a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `diary` command.